# Moving mvc interceptor from module-context to web-application context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Can we move mvc interceptors from individual context file to web-application context.xml 

Thus removing interceptor from individual module context?

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in the web-context as follow:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.package.TheInterceptor" />
    <bean class="com.package.AnotherInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I already tried this with <mvc:mapping path="/*" /> however the interceptor is not being recognised in the module.